# Checking fraud withdrawal with atm bank

Tags: debit-card, fraud, atm, portugal

I have a pre-paid debit card, which I suspect some fraud cash withdrawals have happened at an ATM machine in Portugal (I'm currently staying there).

I'm wondering is there any chance the bank where the money was withdrawn may help me to figure out whether these transactions happened? The company that runs my pre-paid card are being quite unhelpful. Is it normal for a bank where fraud transactions might be occurring to help the victim?

Comment: The Bank where you used the ATM may not entertain you as there is no direct relationship. Generally they would direct you to speak to Issuing Bank and its your Banks responsibility to service you.

Comment: Agreed, talk to your own bank and let them talk to the other bank if appropriate. Though "I suspect" isn't exatly a strong statement.

Comment: but what if my bank isnt calculating things correctly, and they are saying there is a withdrawal when there isnt? This does seem to be the case, and Im trying to figure out a way to check it. I know it sounds strange, but im not sure I fully trust this bank (yet)